# Printing data using vm on Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-ng-repeat

I just started working on a new project which was started.

The last dev was using `vm`, and I need to print some data

Here I have the ctrl

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular
    .module('palpatine')
    .controller('RotationsCtrl', RotationsCtrl);

  /* @ngInject */
  function RotationsCtrl (Rotations, $rootScope, $state) {
    /*jshint validthis: true */
    var vm = this;
    vm.data = Rotations;

    console.log(vm.data);
   }
})();
```

than `console.log(vm.data)` returns an obj like this

```
[{
    "_id": "5653e0fee890e41700946a75",
    "name": "Mtg Rotation 112415 - SR",
    "group": {
      "_id": "563166b302d8831700dfc707",
      "object_name": "rotation",
      "name": "Mortgage",
      "__v": 0,
      "updated_on": "2015-10-29T00:22:11.868Z",
      "created_on": "2015-10-29T00:22:11.868Z"
    }, {
    "_id": "5653e0fe946a75",
    "name": "Mtg Rotation 112415 - JR",
    "group": {
      "_id": "700dfc707",
      "object_name": "rotation 2",
      "name": "Home Mortgage",
      "__v": 7,
      "updated_on": "2015-10-29T00:22:11.868Z",
      "created_on": "2015-10-29T00:22:11.868Z"
    }]
```

all I need is to render that `data.name` in an `ul - li`

let's say like this

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li ng-repeat="datum in vm.data.name">
      {{datum}}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

what can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop through a `vm.data` then print `name` from the each object like `datum.name`.

**Markup**

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" dropdown-menu>
    <li ng-repeat="datum in vm.data">
      {{datum.name}}
    </li>
</ul>
```